# Java Variables of Interface type

Tags: java, interface

I know that object which is assigned to the reference variable whose type is an interface could be an instance of a class that implements the interface. But for the following code blocks:

```
public interface foo {
    public abstract void method_1();
}

class bar implements foo {  
    @Overide
    public void method_1() { //Implementation... }

    public void method_2() { //Do some thing... } 
}
.....

foo variable = new bar();
variable.method_1(); // OK;
variable.method_2(); // Is it legal?
```

Is it possible to make the *variable* (whose declared type is foo but actual type is bar) call the  *method*_2 which is not declared in the interface ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can cast:

```
((bar)variable).method_2();
```

But you probably shouldn't.  The whole point of an interface is to only use the methods it provides.  If they're not sufficient, then don't use the interface.

Answer (score 2):

`variable.method_2()` won't compile as `variable` is of type `foo`. `foo` does not have a method `method_2()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not.  If you want access to `method_2`, you have to declare the type of `variable` to be `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

`Is it possible to make the variable (whose declared type is foo but actual type is bar) call the method_2 which is not declared in the interface ?`

Not its not possible. It will be a compile time error.

There is other standard deviation also in your code

1. Interface and class names should be in upper camel case (this is UpperCamelCase).

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not legal.  However, you can inspect the type at runtime and cast to the correct type:

```
if (variable instanceof bar) ((bar)variable).method_2();
```

(Strictly speaking you can cast without the `instanceof` check if you know for sure the type is correct, or are happy to get an exception thrown if you are wrong.)